# C++ Cannot use getter function inherited from base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

The only way I can access `Vehicle::color` from within `Sedan` class, is by reimplementing the getter method. I want to access it from the subclass, without doing so.

```
// Base Class
class Vehicle
{
protected:
    bool windowIsOpen[4];
    int  wheels;
    char *color;

public:
Vehicle(char *color) : color(color){};
char *getColor() { return color; }
};

class Sedan : Vehicle
{
public:
    Sedan(char* color) : Vehicle(color) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Sedan se("green");
    cout<<se.getColor()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: getColor(){return color;}

Comment: This seems like a typo. You need to use `public` inheritance `class Sedan : public Vehicle { ...};`

Comment: Anyway is a better approach providing setters and getters instead of raw protected variable, though is not the point of the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When defining your class, you wrote `class Sedan : Vehicle`. This is effectively the same as `class Sedan : private Vehicle`. In other words, Vehicle is an implementation detail that ain't exposed to users of Sedan. To make this public inheritance, you should write `class Sedan : public Vehicle`.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize inheritance is private by default.

Comment: inheritance is `private` by default for `class`, and `public` by default for `struct`

Comment: It is for classes, not for structs.